# How can I get a bearer token that lasts for more than 30 minutes to use on BigQuery

Tags: oauth, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I'm using a post request like specified on the page(https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-post-request). When I try the example use of api on web, I can get a bearer token, but it only lasts for a short period of time and I need to reset and input manually on my code. Is there a way to get a token that lasts longer?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As you are using [OAuth 2.0 with BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorization), you will need to get a [refresh token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#exchange-authorization-code) which can be used to obtain a new Access Token.